# file_get_contents not displaying any data

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm doing

```
$info = file_get_contents('http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@api.appfigures.com/v2/sales?client_key=CLIENT_KEY');
```

`$info` returns nothing. However, when I put the URL into my browser, JSON appears. I tried using cURL without any luck.

```
$data = array('client_key' => 'CLIENT_KEY');
$link = "http://api.appfigures.com/v2/sales";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($jsonData);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) disabled in your php config?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$url = 'http://api.appfigures.com/v2/sales?client_key=CLIENT_KEY';
$username = 'USERNAME';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```